# HttpURLConnection conn.getRequestProperty return null

Tags: java, http, web, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to push some data to an URL (MDS_CS) for a BES

when i set some Request Headers in my code, and submit the request, the submited request's header is set to **null**.

here is my code :

```
        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);//For receiving the confirmation
        conn.setDoOutput(true);//For sending the data
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");//Post the data to the proxy
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Rim-Push-ID", pushId);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Rim-Push-Title", "-message");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Rim-Push-Type", "browser-message");                 
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Rim-Push-Dest-Port", "7874");            
        //Write the data
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(data.getBytes());
        out.close();

        System.out.println(conn.getHeaderField("X-Rim-Push-ID"));
```

the last line return null when i try to retrieve the **X-Rim-Push-Title** it is **NULL**
only **X-Rim-Push-ID** which is correctly retrieved,

please help me

Comment: You're setting request properties, but getting a header field. Is that on purpose? Personally I would expect `conn.getRequestProperty("X-Rim-Push-ID")` to work.

Comment: to clarify what @Thor84no is saying, `getHeaderField()` is for getting a _response_ header, not a request header that you have previously set.

Comment: true, please, how could i  get the full http post with headers and data i sent ? 
the response from server is 200, but still didn't get my data pushed to blackberry

Comment: @jtahlborn ,@Thor84no , how could i get the full request i submited,

like i said the response from server is 200 but i dubte on my request

Comment: setup some sort of a proxy to watch the http traffic.  i use [charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which works very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not quite sure what you really want to do. But to see what is posted to the server you would have to post it to your own and read the data you receive there.

If you want to see all the REQUEST headers you could:

```
for (String header : conn.getRequestProperties().keySet()) {
   if (header != null) {
     for (String value : conn.getRequestProperties().get(header)) {
        System.out.println(header + ":" + value);
      }
   }
}
```

Or after connecting you can print out the RESPONSE headers:

```
for (String header : conn.getHeaderFields().keySet()) {
   if (header != null) {
     for (String value : conn.getHeaderFields().get(header)) {
        System.out.println(header + ":" + value);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i'm using a simple main method to exec my request i can't debug the sent request!
how " post it to your own and read" could i do it ?

Comment: To post it to your own server the easiest would be a servlet in a servlet container like tomcat. But I dont see why you really need this. As you write all data in your request you should know what you are posting. Did you check how your `data` looks like, did you encode it correctly?

Comment: handling from the post method on a servlet ? am i right ?
the data is encoded! the server return a 200 code back

Comment: Did you actually look at all the headers and a possible response message? Read the InputStream from the response to see what the server returns.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

```
final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
final PostMethod method = new PostMethod(uri);
method.addRequestHeader("X-Rim-Push-Title", "-message");
client.executeMethod(method);
String responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
Header[] headers = method.getResponseHeaders();
```

HttpClient is a much more powerful way of dealing with HTTP than HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

When I  check my headers submitted and the inputstream of request,  I get the 200 ok status, but nothing is sent to device

```
from server: 200 | OK


=======REQUEST===============
request header:X-Rim-Push-ID:pushID:1342694818991
request header:Host:win-uhgr7vs88uz.assabb.com:8080
request header:Content-Length:19
request header:X-Rim-Push-Title:-message
request header:User-Agent:Java/1.6.0_18
request header:POST /push?DESTINATION=bestest%40assa-associates.com&PORT=7874&REQUESTURI=/ HTTP/1.1:null
request header:Content-Type:text/html
request header:Accept:text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
request header:Connection:keep-alive
request header:X-Rim-Push-Dest-Port:7874
request header:X-Rim-Push-Type:browser-message
======Response===============
response header:Date:Thu, 19 Jul 2012 10:47:10 GMT
response header:Content-Length:0
response header:X-RIM-Push-ID:pushID:1342694818991
response header:Via:MDS_5.0.3.26
response header:x-rim-multidest-push-supported:true
response header:Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
response header:x-rim-push-persisted:fals
```