# HttpURLConnection - How to send Headers in setRequestProperty

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send headers in the given URL using Java code like below:

```
URL u = new URL("http://domain:8081/App/mycall");
HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Auth-Token", authToken);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Then in my application I am checking that `Auth-Token` like below:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
        String reqToken = req.getHeader("Auth-Token");
    }
}
```

When I call the above URL in post man with headers then it works fine. But when I run the URL in Java code then `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` always returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be this link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544256/httpurlconnection-conn-getrequestproperty-return-null

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following line before creating the URL fixed my problem:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Sending headers in the given URL now looks like this and it works:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
URL u = new URL("http://domain:8081/App/mycall");
HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Auth-Token", authToken);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```